# FHIR manage of notifications

Tags: notifications, hl7-fhir

I'm trying to manage a `FHIR workflow` based on API Rest for resources CRUD (as Patient, Practitioner and so on).

For workflow handling among different systems I want to use `task` resource, but I don't want to manage the Subscription resource and it's architecture.

So I have a doubt about manage of notifications.

The correct way is: the different systems must apply a polling operation on server to know if there's a `task` resource to consume? Or is it the server to warn the different systems?

The server FHIR I want to use is R4.

**EDIT**

We want to create a interoperability platform about the exchange of data among three systems. Every system is already in production developed by different software house and we can't work on them.

Every system, actually, hasn't got a server FHIR (as the Option B of Workflow architecture).

Every system is available about communication in HL7 v.3 / FHIR

So we want to add a layer with FHIR Server as the below image.

[image: Target architecture]

In this case:

- if `System A` sends to FHIR server a resource (i.e. Appointment) then `System B` take this appointment to process in its environment. How works the schema of communication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FHIR [workflow communication patterns](https://build.fhir.org/workflow-communications.html) page defines a number of architecture alternatives.  One possibility is to create the Task on the fulfiller's system.  In that case, no need for polling or subscription.  If the Task is created on the placer's system or an intermediary system and you're sticking with pure REST, then the fulfilling system will need to either have a subscription that will result in them receiving a notification about the Task or they'll have to poll.  Other non-RESTful options include POSTing to a "process task" operation on the fulfilling system or sending a FHIR message to the fulfilling system.

Comment: Dear, thank you very much for your reply. Please, I've update my question, can you reply again?

Comment: There are three options - the Task lives on the placing system, so if the filler updates the Task, the placer automatically knows; the placer subscribes to the system where the Task resides (filler or intermediary) and is pushed notifications of updates; the placer polls the system where the Task resides to see if there are updates.

Comment: Thank you very much ;)